# Why does eval() give undefined value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, eval

I am working in JavaScript coding. I have created a text area with name `OQ_0` and value `"0"`. When i use `eval()` method for that field in JavaScript it is giving the value `undefined`. The below are the part of JavaScript code

```
var tempOpenQtyStr = "document.InitiateReturnsForm.OQ" + "_" + 0; 
var tempOpenxQtyStr = eval(tempOpenQtyStr).value;
alert('Manuals =' + document.InitiateReturnsForm.OQ_0.value);
alert('eval(tempOpenxQtyStr ) =' + eval(tempOpenxQtyStr));
alert('eval(tempOpenxQtyStr).value =' + eval(tempOpenxQtyStr).value);
```

Output:

```
Manuals = 0
eval(tempOpenxQtyStr ) = 0 --- Here it is suppose to show "[object]"
eval(tempOpenxQtyStr).value = undefined.
```

Kindly help me out what is change to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post the html part relating to this, just so that we can see the DOM, Thanks

Comment: Stop using eval()!!  This whole thing is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use `document.InitiateReturnsForm["OQ_" + 0].value`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
alert('eval(tempOpenxQtyStr ) = ' + eval(tempOpenQtyStr));
alert('eval(tempOpenxQtyStr).value = ' + eval(tempOpenQtyStr).value);
```

In the second and third alert you are evaluating the second variable which stores the value of the first evaluated object. That's why the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert('eval(tempOpenxQtyStr ) =' + eval(tempOpenxQtyStr));
```

Since you put a string, not an object, inside tempOpenxQtyStr, it evaluates that string and returns 0.

```
alert('eval(tempOpenxQtyStr).value =' + eval(tempOpenxQtyStr).value);
```

Here you're using a method on a variable that contains a string. That doesn't work. It doesn't have that method, that's why it returns undefinied.

You might want to try doing `eval(tempOpenxQtyStr.value)` instead of `eval(tempOpenxQtyStr).value` since the last one does basically nothing, just evaluating an object and then fetching the objects value (it doesn't eval the value itself).